# Robot Framework Tests Failing on Edge webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, microsoft-edge

### My Config given below:

Win 10 Build: 16299.431
Edge MS WebDriver Version: 10.0.16299.15
robotframework (3.0.4)
robotframework-seleniumlibrary (3.2.0)
selenium (3.141.0)
python 3.5

---

My Robot Tests which are working fine on chrome keep failing on Edge with above config. That too erratically. So far I have run 3 times - every time it has failed on different sections of code.
Any insights would really help

Comment: How do they fail? Do you get errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: Thanks Bryan
Some types -
 - Xpaths which work on chrome do not work on edge. Eg today there was a case where by one xpath that uses contains did not run on edge while it was fine on chrome. If I use equal (and not contain) it works on edge.
- Execution notably slow on edge
- Edge is relatively poor at low level selenium command like
Scroll, mouse over etc. Poor as in it does not find element
- Execution where Execute JavaScript  keyword works fine on chrome errors out on Edge

Comment: @ Pooja, Try to provide a detailed steps to reproduce the issue. We will try to follow your steps and try to check for the issue. With above information, we are not able to find any cause for this issue.

Comment: Thanks Bran/Deepak. However, the run keeps failing on different places due to reasons given above; hence there is not 1 flow which I can provide to reproduce.     For now we are running all scripts on 17134 version of Win 10 - where all is well... What is perplexing is why these errors are not coming on 16299 version of WIN10 as opposed to 17134. May be Edge Driver supports only latest

Answer (score 1):

Selenium 3 supports legacy edge driver, and if your edge browser version is > 75, then you are unlucky.

it's lengthy.

follow https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools to install msedge-selenium-tools.
create your own keyword "open edgebrowser" and add though custom library.

or, wait for selenium release of version 4, and Robot GitHub to adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised the two things which helped are:
- Installing NodeJs - not sure how but the code which was breaking for Execute Java Script started to work after installing node js on Edge.
- Another thing which helped was not to keep the InternetExploreWebDriver and MicrosoftWeb Driver in 1 Folder in PATH Variable.